# MIDL. Why callback c++ interface doesn't renewed after method added to idl?

Tags: c++, com, atl, midl

I try to implement callback interface with COM techonlogy and have IDL like that:

```
library LogstreamScannerLib
{
    importlib("stdole2.tlb");
    [
        uuid(8CACF064-EF0E-4496-92D5-F26C64A5858A)      
    ]
    dispinterface _IMyClassEvents
    {
        properties:
        methods:    
            [id(1)] void SomeMethod([in] int data); 
    };

    [
        uuid(AFC03FCD-01A9-4F38-994F-BA98E57FF64E)      
    ]   
    coclass MyComClass
    {
        [default] interface IMyClass;
        [default, source] dispinterface _IMyClassEvents;
    };


};
```

Please note, IMyClass has SomeMethod declaration but I can't figure out why doesn't it appear in my auto generated classes when I recompile/rebuild project.

It's always declared as empty:

```
   MIDL_INTERFACE("8CACF064-EF0E-4496-92D5-F26C64A5858A")
    _IMyClassEvents : public IDispatch
    {
    };
```

What I do wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have found the issue.

When you use  "Implement Connection Point Wizard" you should choose generate connection point from "Type Library" (instead of "IDL"). You see this choice in combobox and should change default option IDL -> Type Lib.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean using COM Connection Points?  Here is a link to the [ATL Connection Points](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h7kad5hw.aspx) documentation in MSDN.

If you are trying to figure out how to generate the event proxy class, look at point 4 in the [Adding Connection Points to an Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7bkz4x17.aspx) and here is a [MSDN tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h7xedd1%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for adding a event.  You can regenerate the event proxy classes as many times as you like.

What I find is that I always have to go looking for where to generate the proxy classes...

Comment: Thank you, @Shane! I have read that article(s) but it looks like I did everything right. When I tried to add methods to connection point via wizard I was told they should appear in MIDL file - it fails for me. MIDL interface stays the same

Comment: To be honest, I never use the VS IDE to change the IDL file, I just edit it manually...  I find it easier.